# Multiple plots in R by connecting two points using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Suppose I have a data set of this form.

[image]

I would like to make one for `X1` and one for `X2` by connecting LCL and UCL for each model.  The expected outcome should look like this figure

[image]

The lower point is the LCL and the upper point is the UCL of each model.
Any help is appreciated.
here is data using `dput()` function

```
> dput(mydata)
structure(list(x1m1 = c(0.5, 1), x1m2 = c(0.2, 1.5), x1m3 = c(0.5, 
1.25), x2m1 = c(0.24, 0.98), x2m2 = c(0.1, 1.4), x2m3 = c(1, 
2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("LCL", "UCL"))
```

Comment: Could you provide the an example of the input data with `dput()`? Your input data has multiple column levels (X,model,lcl,values), which is impossible to represent in a single standard dataframe (to my knowledge). Did you already parsed the data?

Comment: see the data. you should be able to use it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution using the tidyverse (in this case dplyr and ggplot)

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata$point <- rownames(mydata) # integrate Rownames in dataframe

# pivot the data longer and separate the cols
mydata <- mydata %>% pivot_longer(-c(point),
                        names_to="X",
                        values_to="value"
                        ) %>%
  separate(X,into = c("X","model"), sep=2)  %>%# separate the stringcol
  pivot_wider(names_from = point, values_from=value) #pivot wider again to separate LCL and UCL Column

# use 
ggplot(mydata,aes(x=X,color=model,ymin = LCL, ymax=UCL))+
  geom_linerange(position=position_dodge(width=0.20))
  # postion argument to dodge so that the lines are not plottet above each other
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: If I want to add one point in each line? How can I do? Here is the data set 
`structure(list(x1m1 = c(0.5, 1, 0.6), x1m2 = c(0.2, 1.5, 0.25
), x1m3 = c(0.5, 1.25, 1), x2m1 = c(0.24, 0.98, 0.7), x2m2 = c(0.1, 
1.4, 0.8), x2m3 = c(1, 2, 0.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("LCL", 
"UCL", "mean"))` @Sandwichnick