# Adding point in geom_linerange() and reduce the gap in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question is related to
[Multiple plots in R by connecting two points using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68030359/multiple-plots-in-r-by-connecting-two-points-using-ggplot2)
I would like to add one point (mean row) in each line. The data set is

```
> dput(mydata)
structure(list(x1m1 = c(0.5, 1, 0.6), x1m2 = c(0.2, 1.5, 0.25
), x1m3 = c(0.5, 1.25, 1), x2m1 = c(0.24, 0.98, 0.7), x2m2 = c(0.1, 
1.4, 0.8), x2m3 = c(1, 2, 0.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("LCL", 
"UCL", "mean"))

> mydata
     x1m1 x1m2 x1m3 x2m1 x2m2 x2m3
LCL   0.5 0.20 0.50 0.24  0.1  1.0
UCL   1.0 1.50 1.25 0.98  1.4  2.0
mean  0.6 0.25 1.00 0.70  0.8  0.6
```

And reduce the gap between `X1` and `X2`. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To add a point to lien ranges, use `geom_pointrange`. But the data must first be transposed and prepared.
Note that in the posted data, the mean value of `x2m2` is not between `LCL` and `UCL`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mydata %>% t() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(model = row.names(.)) %>%
  mutate(id = substr(model, 1, 2), model = substring(model, 3)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(model, mean, colour = model)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = LCL, ymax = UCL)) +
  facet_wrap(~ id)
```

[image]